# "Index -1 does not have a value" when I click on a DataGridView row

Tags: c#, datagridview

This seems like a very strange issue, but maybe I'm just missing something obvious.

I stripped everything down to bare-bones.  Take a Windows form and put a DataGridView on it.  In the _Load event, put this code:

```
   List<Mystery> myst = new List<Mystery>();
   //myst.Add(new Mystery() { Name = "First" });
   dataGridView1.DataSource = myst;
   dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
   myst.Clear();
   myst.Add(new Mystery() { Name = "First" });
   myst.Add(new Mystery() { Name = "Second" });
   myst.Add(new Mystery() { Name = "Third" });
   dataGridView1.DataSource = myst;
```

The class doesn't seem to be relevant, I used:

```
class Mystery
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I load up the form, if I click on one of the rows, I get this error: "Index -1 does not have a value".

However, if I un-comment the second line of code, I don't have the problem.

Or, if I comment out the third line of code, it works fine.

Or, if instead of clearing the list, I re-instantiate it.

The error seems to be caused if the *first time* you bind a particular list to a grid, that list has zero objects in it.

It's easy enough to make the code work by just checking to see if the list has > 0 objects and if not, bind the grid to null instead, but that seems inelegant, and I'd like to know why the error is happening.  Should it just be a general rule that you check for 0 count before binding a list to a grid?  Or is there something weird in my setup or system?

Comment: Yup.  I tried changing several grid properties and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Sometimes, procedures related to DataGridView don't work when called from the form constructor or its load event. In that case, implement the FormActivate event and call the procedure in the first FormActivate.

Comment: It is something to do with the List binding and the now you see it; now you dont gyrations with the List.  Use a BindingList<T> and you wont have to set the DataSource to null then give it back.